# Parsing text file with symbol

Tags: c++, parsing, dialog

I cant parse all text from .txt file
But when I run my code, I don't get what I wanted :(

My code:

```
int main()
{
  /* inside "logMsg.txt"
  1/ [111]{1}(text line from 111);
  2/ [222]{2}(text line from 222);
  3/ [333]{3}(text line from 333);
  */

  ifstream textfile("logMsg.txt");

  string log_line;
  string log_time;
  string log_type;
  string log_comment;

  // Get line number
  getline(textfile, log_line, '/');

  // Get Time by unix
  getline(textfile, log_time, '[');
  getline(textfile, log_time, ']');

  // Get type of the function
  getline(textfile, log_type, '{');
  getline(textfile, log_type, '}');

  // Get comment from data_
  getline(textfile, log_comment, '(');
  getline(textfile, log_comment, ')');

  cout << "Line Of the log: " << log_line << "\n";
  cout << "Type of the log: " << log_type << "\n";
  cout << "Time of the log: " << log_time << "\n";
  cout << "Comment of the log :" << log_comment << "\n";
}
```

Console:

```
Line Of the log: 1
Type of the log: 1
Time of the log: 111
Comment of the log :text line from 111
```

I wanted the parser to read all the lines, but the result is completely different

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I trying to get the following result:

```
Line Of the log: 1, 2, 3,
Type of the log: 1, 2, 3,
Time of the log: 111, 222, 333,
Comment of the log: text line from 111, text line from 222, text line from 333,
```

plz help :(

Comment: getline clears the string when called. If you call it twice you are left only with what you read the second time, i.e.  `getline(textfile, log_time, ']');` gives you the last character before ], which is 1. I also recommend separating getting the lines from parsing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using regular expressions for this:

- The example below just parses each line using a given pattern. You may need to modify it, for instance, allowing whitespaces around certain fields.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/bKE8dcYPE)

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>  // getline

int main() {
    const std::string input{"1/ [111]{1}(text line from 111);\n2/ [222]{2}(text line from 222);\n3/ [333]{3}(text line from 333);"};
    std::istringstream iss{input};

    std::string line{};
    while (std::getline(iss, line))
    {
        const std::regex pattern{R"(([\d+])/\s*\[(\d+)\]\{(\d+)\}\(([^)]+)\);)"};
        std::smatch matches{};
        if (std::regex_match(line, matches, pattern))
        {
            std::cout << fmt::format ("Line: {}, type: {}, time: {}, comment: {}\n",
                matches[1].str(), matches[2].str(), matches[3].str(), matches[4].str());
        }
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Line: 1, type: 111, time: 1, comment: text line from 111
//   Line: 2, type: 222, time: 2, comment: text line from 222
//   Line: 3, type: 333, time: 3, comment: text line from 333
```

- Should you want a different output (e.g. as it seems you suggest in your question, print all the line numbers, then all the times, and so on), you may want to use `std::vectors` for keeping that information, and printing it at the end.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/7x7rnGdhW)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // copy
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <iterator>  // ostream_iterator
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>  // getline

int main() {
    const std::string input{"1/ [111]{1}(text line from 111);\n2/ [222]{2}(text line from 222);\n3/ [333]{3}(text line from 333);"};
    std::istringstream iss{input};

    std::vector<std::string> numbers{};
    std::vector<std::string> types{};
    std::vector<std::string> times{};
    std::vector<std::string> comments{};
    std::string line{};
    while (std::getline(iss, line))
    {
        const std::regex pattern{R"(([\d+])/\s*\[(\d+)\]\{(\d+)\}\(([^)]+)\);)"};
        std::smatch matches{};
        if (std::regex_match(line, matches, pattern))
        {
            numbers.push_back(matches[1]);
            types.push_back(matches[2]);
            times.push_back(matches[3]);
            comments.push_back(matches[4]);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Line of the log: ";
    std::copy(numbers.cbegin(), numbers.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Type of the log: ";
    std::copy(types.cbegin(), types.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Time of the log: ";
    std::copy(times.cbegin(), times.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Comment of the log: ";
    std::copy(comments.cbegin(), comments.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Line of the log: 1, 2, 3, 
//   Type of the log: 111, 222, 333, 
//   Time of the log: 1, 2, 3, 
//   Comment of the log: text line from 111, text line from 222, text line from 333,
```

- Although you'd better use a single `std::vector` of `struct`s, with proper types for the numbers, types and times. In this case, you would need to convert the strings from `matches` to the `struct`'s `int`s (you could do that with `std::stoi`).

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/z5x6avsfz)

```cpp
struct LineInfo
{
    int number{};
    int type{};
    int time{};
    std::string comment{};
};
std::vector<LineInfo> line_infos{};
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your source code, I assume that you are learning about the C++ iostream functionality. Regexes and stuff may be still too complicated in the beginning. So, let us try to survive with normal iostream functionalities.

Basically you should know that there are 2 major types of input:

- Formatted input
- Unformatted input

To get an overview, please read in the CPP reference about that [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream).

You know about the formatted IO already, because you are alreay using statements like `std::cout << "Hello" << '\n';` or `std::cin >> word >> count`. Formatted input function read characters from the stream, interprete them (formatted) and convert them to the target type. For example, if you write `int number; std::cin >> number;`, and then press the keys 1 then 2 then 3, the software will read characters '1', '2' and '3' and then convert that to an integer number.

Behind the scenes there is a little bit more, but this explanation is good for now. Please note that the IO-operators, like the extract operator `>>` always return the stream that they are invoked with. And this allows chaining of such statements. Example for `std::cin >> word >> count`. First `std::cin >> word` is executed. All characters until a white space will be read and then converted to a string and stored in `word`. The `>>`operation will return the stream for which it was called, in our case: `std::cin`. So, after reading the word, we have now the statement `std::cin >> count` left. Then the count will be read. Delimiting white space will be ignored. That is why and how it is basically working.

A further important property is that the `>>` operation skips any potential white space (including new line characters '\n') and then starts the conversion. It will stop reading and consuming characters from the input stream, if the read character cannot be converted to the target variable any longer. This again includes white space.

If you have `1/ [111]{1}(text line from 111);` in the stream and write `stream >> number;`, then it will read character 1 and start the conversion to an integer. Then it sees the following '/' character. It stops reading and converts '1' to the number 1, But, it does NOT extract the '/' from the stream. It is still in and can and must be read. So, if we define a `char` variable `c1` and write `stream >> number >> c1` then first the number will be read to `number` and the '/' will be read to `c1`. Spaces will be ignored.

By using this mechanism you can read the first part of the string like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::istringstream test{ R"(1/[111]{1}(text line from 111);)" };

int main() {
    int line, time, type;
    char c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6;
    std::string comment;

    test >> line >> c1 >> c2 >> time >> c3 >> c4 >> type >> c5 >> c6;

    return 0;
}
```

(The cx variables are just dummies)

The variables will then be:
[image]

This is as expected. Spaces will not disturb here in any way.

Now the next part, the comment, so the `text line from 111` in the string. As you see, it contains spaces. And since foramtted input functions stop conversion at a white space, we cannot use formatted input functions like `>>` to read the complete text into one string variable.

Now we need to use unformatted input functions like [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). This will read all characters until a given delimiter and stores this in a `std::string` variable. The delimiter is usually '\n', so that `std::getline` will read a complete line until the newline character '\n'. But we can also specify a different delimiter, like for example a ')' or whatever.

Please remember that formatted input functions return a reference to the given string. So, `test >> line >> c1 >> c2 >> time >> c3 >> c4 >> type >> c5 >> c6` will result in the stream `test`. And since `std::getline` expects a stream as first parameter, we can past the complete long input statement into the `std::getline` and write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::istringstream test{ R"(1/[111]{1}(text line from 111);)" };

int main() {
    int line, time, type;
    char c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6;
    std::string comment;

    std::getline(test >> line >> c1 >> c2 >> time >> c3 >> c4 >> type >> c5 >> c6, comment, ')');

    return 0;
}
```

The result will be

[image]

And guess what? `std::getline` also returns the stream. Knowing that and the above, we can come to the final solution for one line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::istringstream test{ R"(1/[111]{1}(text line from 111);)" };

int main() {
    int line, time, type;
    char c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6, c7;
    std::string comment;

    std::getline(test >> line >> c1 >> c2 >> time >> c3 >> c4 >> type >> c5 >> c6, comment, ')') >> c7;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Next: Check of successful operation of an IO operation.

We should always check the result of any IO operation. But how? I explained already that the IO-operations return a reference to the stream. And with that we can write for example:

```
if (std::getline(test >> line >> c1 >> c2 >> time >> c3 >> c4 >> type >> c5 >> c6, comment, ')') >> c7) {
...
}
```

But how? As a said. The input function will return a reference to the stream and then we have left: `if (test)`. And this works, because the bool operator of the streams is overwritten (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)). And this bool operator will tell us, if we had some error or not.

So, to read and output all data, we could write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::istringstream test{ R"(1/[111]{1}(text line from 111);
  2/ [222]{2}(text line from 222);
  3/ [333]{3}(text line from 333);)" };

int main() {
    int line, time, type;
    char c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6, c7;
    std::string comment;
    while (std::getline(test >> line >> c1 >> c2 >> time >> c3 >> c4 >> type >> c5 >> c6, comment, ')') >> c7)
       std::cout << "Line: " << line << "\tTime: " << time << "\tType: " << type << "\tComment: " << comment << '\n';
}
```

This shows, how it is basically working.

---

But, you need a different output format. And this is not somehow horizontal but vertical. Therefore we need to store what we read in some dynamic container. I hope that you know about the `std::vector`. If not, then please tell me and I will help you also here.

So we will not read the variables, output them and then forget about it, but store them and use them later.

You may have heard that C++ is a so called object oriented language. And here we put data in the methods working on this data into one `class` or `struct`.

This may look like:

```
struct LogLine {
    int line{};
    long time{};
    int type{};
    std::string comment{};
};
```

This is the data part. Now, we need the methods for this data. And the only thing that we need is input. For this we can add the extract operation `>>` to this struct. The syntax is:

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, LineInfo& l) { ....
```

Combining with the thing that we learned above we can write now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::istringstream test{ R"(1/[111]{1}(text line from 111);
  2/ [222]{2}(text line from 222);
  3/ [333]{3}(text line from 333);)" };

struct LogLine {
    // Data
    int line{};
    long time{};
    int type{};
    std::string comment{};

    // Methods
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, LogLine& l) {
        char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7;
        return std::getline(is >> l.line >> c1 >> c2 >> l.time >> c3 >> c4 >> l.type >> c5 >> c6 >> std::ws, l.comment, ')') >> c7;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const LogLine& l) {
        return os << "Line: " << l.line << "\tTime: " << l.time << "\tType: " << l.type << "\tComment: " << l.comment;
    }
};
```

That is by far better.

And now we can create a `std::vector` for this data and even better, encapsulate that in an additional class.

Like for example so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

std::istringstream test{ R"(1/[111]{1}(text line from 111);
  2/ [222]{2}(text line from 222);
  3/ [333]{3}(text line from 333);)" };

struct LogLine {
    // Data
    int line{};
    long time{};
    int type{};
    std::string comment{};

    // Methods
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, LogLine& l) {
        char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7;
        return std::getline(is >> l.line >> c1 >> c2 >> l.time >> c3 >> c4 >> l.type >> c5 >> c6 >> std::ws, l.comment, ')') >> c7;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const LogLine& l) {
        char c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7;
        return os << "Line: " << l.line << "\tTime: " << l.time << "\tType: " << l.type << "\tComment: " << l.comment;
    }
};



struct Log {
    // Data
    std::vector<LogLine> logLines;
    // Methods
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Log& l) {
        l.logLines.clear(); LogLine tmp{};
        while (is >> tmp) l.logLines.push_back(tmp);
        return is;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Log& l) {
        os << "\nLine Of the log : "; for (const LogLine& ll : l.logLines) os << ll.line << ", ";
        os << "\nType of the log : "; for (const LogLine& ll : l.logLines) os << ll.type << ", ";
        os << "\nTime of the log : "; for (const LogLine& ll : l.logLines) os << ll.time << ", ";
        os << "\nComment of the log : "; for (const LogLine& ll : l.logLines) os << ll.comment << ", ";
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
    Log log;
    
    // Read and parse all data
    test >> log;

    // Show debug output
    std::cout << log;
}
```

And this gives you the the idiomatic correct solution.

As you saw, we split one big problem in many many small problems. First solving the input part, and then encapsulating everthing into structs.

The result is a one liner in main for reading and parsing the whole file.

If you have questions, then I am happy to answer.